# Задать в регулярном выражении квантификатор, который был бы ленивым в обе стороны

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, скажем:

```
aabbcc
```

Если задать ленивый квантификатор вот так:

```
a.*?b.*?c
```

...то получаем, естественно, `aabbc`. А хотелось бы получить минимально возможное соответствие, а именно `abbc`. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Так работает - `a{1}.*?b.*?c` ? Или так `a{1}[^a]*b.*c` ?

Comment: Так - `a[^a]*b.*?c`

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, именно то, что нужно! Спасибо!

Comment: Тогда уж `a[^abc]*b[^ac]*c` будет ещё лучше (наверное)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае если `a`, `b` и `c` являются односимвольными строками, используйте

```
a[^a]*b.*?c
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Os8eh9/1).

В случае если `a`, `b` и `c` являются многосимвольными строками, используйте

```
a(?:(?!a).)*?b.*?c
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Os8eh9/2).

Чтобы найти совпадения в тех случаях, когда `a`, `b` и `c` могут находится на разных строках, `.` можно заменить на `[\s\S]` или - лучше - использовать модификатор вроде `dotall`, `(?s)` в начале шаблона или аналогичный флаг в каждом конкретном языке.

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Os8eh9/3).

Comment: Спасибо ещё раз. Я бы рад принять ответ, но не знаю, как это сделать, и никакой галочки, о которой пишут, не вижу :(

Comment: @YuriyO. "*Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ [отмечен как решение вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).*". [Здесь даже есть скриншоты](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: Спасибо, готово. В упор её не видел :)